# How to get Id_token after successful signup in keycloak?

Tags: oauth, keycloak

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/registrations?client_id=alpha&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://alpha.app&scope=openid

The above is taking me to keycloak signup page and after successful signup redirecting back to my app. But here I want to get the user id of the registered user or any info about the user just registered but after redirection, I'm only getting session_state and code params. How to get id_token or anything from that I can get registered user details

https://alpha.app/#session_state=5ad94adb-39f5-4664-abc8&code=7ba2-488e-9bf4-ad7b1a969904.b3d26ed7-649a-454d-b6ff-246792277042

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your question, I can assume that you are using authorization code grant type. You need to exchange the received authorization code for a token.

Specification: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth

Keycloak token endpoint : http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/token

All the available OIDC endpoints: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}/.well-known/openid-configuration